# RoR: How can I get all of my users microposts to show up in one place?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want them to show up on the home page. I think I may be having trouble because there is a belong_to has_many relationship. Each micropost belongs_to an user and each user has_many microposts. I got them to show up on the users page (but that is a list of just that users microposts, not everyones which is what I want on the home page). In case its not clear from the view. I want two seperate lists. One list of everyones microposts that has the kind "purchase" and another list of all the "sale" microposts. Kind is a column in the micropost database. Right now nothing shows up and there are no errors...

Here is the app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb

```
<div id="purchases list">
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @purchases unless @purchases.nil? %>
  </ol>
</div>

<div id="sales list">
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @sales unless @sales.nil? %>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Here is the app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb (im not sure if this is important)

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method:  :delete,
                                     confirm: "You sure?",
                                     title:   micropost.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

It may be important that I have use scopes in the definition of the microposts in the model file (micropost.rb) as such

```
scope :purchases, where(:kind => "purchase")
  scope :sales, where(:kind => "sale")
```

here is the microposts_controller.rb

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: :destroy


  def home
    @microposts=Micropost.all
    @purchases=@microposts.collect{ |m| m if m.kind == "purchase"}.compact
    @sales=@microposts.collect{ |m| m if m.kind == "sale"}.compact
  def show

    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts
    @purchases= @microposts.purchases
    @sales = @microposts.sales

  end
```

and here is the users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, 
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @micropost=Micropost.new
    @microposts = @user.microposts
    @purchases= @microposts.purchases
    @sales = @microposts.sales
  end

  def home

    @microposts = Micropost.all
    @purchases = @microposts.collect{ |m| m if m.kind == "purchase"}.compact
    @sales = @microposts.collect{ |m| m if m.kind == "sale"}.compact
  end
```

Comment: You appear to be missing an `end` for `MicropostsController#home`. I would expect that to cause an error, so it's probably a typo?

Comment: Also, I think `.select{|m| m.kind = 'purchase'}` would be superior to `.collect{|m| m if m.kind = 'purchase'}.compact`, but that doesn't directly address your problem.

Comment: you are right about the type. That didn't fix the error though. And .select worked well in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `XController` will look for a view template in `app/views/X`, so you need to move your `home.html.erb` out of `app/views/static_pages` and into to either `app/views/users` or `app/views/microposts`.  Also, why do you have identical `home` methods in both controllers?

If that doesn't work for you I'd want to know (a) what URL you're browsing to, and (b) what's in your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: wow that worked. I had to move home.html.erb into the microposts folder and change the routes.rb file to route there first instead of to static_pages/home. thank you